# Having issue in my background image when I mouse over to particular div

Tags: html

Having issue in my background image when I mouse over to particular div, I want to bring a image, When I a:hover to p1 div.How do I do this? but The image should be in p1  div via, because I need to give anchor tag.

Here is my html

```
<div class="product">
<div class="p1"><a href="#"><img src="img/dynamic/boysproducts-01.png"/></a></div><!--endof p1-->
<div class="p2"><a href="#">Text Descripition</a></div><!--endof p2-->
</div><!--endofproduct-->

Here is my css


 .product
    {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    }

    .p1
    {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#333333;
    }

    .p1 a
    {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    }


    .p1 a:hover
    {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-image:url(../img/dynamic/girlsproduct-01.png);
    }
```

Comment: Use javascripts hide() and show() function to do this along with mouse event handler\

Comment: We can do it css itself , I have done lot. I am marketing job. I forgot that one. I am individual person doing marketing and coding. so immediately not clicking for me. if you can help me in css it is great